# My private repository returns binary content on a curl GET request

Tags: docker, curl

Here is the request and its response:

```
$ curl -v -X GET domain.com:5000/v2/_catalog/
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 165.227.161.233...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to domain.com (165.227.161.233) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2/_catalog/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: domain.com:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 7)
* Closing connection 0
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X201 ~]
$ curl -v -X GET domain.com:5000/v2/_catalog/
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 165.227.161.233...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to domain.com (165.227.161.233) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2/_catalog/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: domain.com:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 7)
* Closing connection 0
```

Here is how I created the registry in a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:latest
    container_name: registry
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ~/dev/docker/registries/registry:/var/lib/registry
```

My docker version is:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:   17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:11:14 2017
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:09:47 2017
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error which occurred due to ssl stuff because my local docker registry was secured so you have to mention **https://...** in the start of the local registry url

`curl  --key <ssl key file> --cacert <ssl pem file> -X GET https://<your local registry url >:<your port>/v2/_catalog`

or insecure:

`curl -k  -X GET https://<your local registry url >:<your port>/v2/_catalog`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recover the actual content of the response from your server  using the `-o`  option  like :

```
curl –k –o body.txt -X GET domain.com:5000/v2/_catalog/
```

and then, change the extension of your file `.txt` to correponds to the expected  Content-Type format provided by  your server.

```
curl -i -X GET domain.com:5000/v2/_catalog/
```

check :

```
Content-Type: image/png, application/json , etc
```

the data sent by server may be coming for a wrong format

Comment: Something new and puzzling... I get a `301 Moved Permanently` on the `curl -v domain.com:5000/v2/_catalog/` as well as on your command. But the `docker push domain.com:5000/myimage` command still works just fine.